# tinymce media plugin

Tags: tinymce

I'm using tinymce 3.4.9 and I have a problem.
when I insert a video from youtube, i see that the video has been insert to the textarea, but when I use

```
alert(tinyMCE.get('TextInp' id).getContent());
```

Or

```
alert(oTinyMCE.get('TextInp' id).getContent());
```

Or

```
alert($('#TextInp' id).html());
```

It's print (as alert) all the text except the youtube embed (iframe i think it should be). It's gone.

I'm Initializing the tinymce like this:

```
var oTinyMCE=new tinymce.Editor('TextInp' id, {
            theme : "advanced",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : alignMe  ,
            width: MCEWidth,
            height: MCEHeight,
            relative_urls : false,
            remove_script_host : false,
            plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount",
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,image,cleanup,|,insertdate",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media",
            language: myLang,
            directionality : dir
        });
        oTinyMCE.render();
```

What can be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your tag gets stripped out. You will have to modify the tinymce settings [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) and valid_children to your needs.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand you.
What sould I do?

Comment: I put the code under 'Full XHTML rule set' and it didn't help.